# Will silent push notification works if user turn off notification for the app?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, silent

Planning to use **silent notification** to refresh it's **data** when necessary. But I am worried that if users do not **permit** push notification, the app will not refresh data.

I am not sure if silent notification is different from normal notification in regards to **permission**.

Anybody has experienced this matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about "data only messages" from firebase, yes, you will receive them normally as they don't use the Notification Manager API to publish a notification